# Getting an error when attempting to create an Email Quick Action in Sandbox

Tags: email, quickaction, deliverability

Why am I getting this error when attempting to create an Email Quick Action in a sandbox?

Error: Invalid Data. Review all error messages below to correct your data.

[image: error message image]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to turn on Email Delivery from No Access or System Email Only to All Email in Email > Deliverability.

This will show the "Relationship Field" option that is hidden for some reason in the above error.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible reason for this issue:

I was trying to create the Email action for a managed object which didn't have activities enabled. It threw the same (generic) error.

Once I checked the 'Track Activities' checkbox for the object, I was able to successfully create the Action.